# CVS checkout is hanging using ant

Tags: ant, cvs

I'm using ant to checkout folder from cvs:

```
<cvspass cvsroot=":ext:breddy@cvs.oatsystems.com:/usr/local/cvs" password="passwd"/>

<cvs cvsRSH="ssh" cvsRoot=":ext:breddy@cvs.oatsystems.com:/usr/local/cvs" package="atf/home" dest="." passfile=".cvspass">
```

output comes like this and hangs. I have waited up to half an hour.

```
Buildfile: build.xml

test:

checkout:
```

It hangs like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CVS Ant tasks simply make system calls to the CVS command itself, so there's really no advantage of using the CVS tasks rather than simply calling CVS yourself.

I've had nothing but problems with the CVS tasks, so I simply use the `<exec>` task to take care of CVS checkouts, commits, etc. In the end, the end, calling CVS via the `<exec>` task isn't any more inefficient, doesn't take any more typing, and is just as easy to understand.

---

### Response to bhasker

> Hi thank you for response. But giving password in thr root is supported only for pserver . But i'm using ext. It gives following error cvs checkout: CVSROOT password specification is only valid for cvs checkout: pserver connection method. [checkout aborted] - bhasker

I've downloaded the Ant source and looked at the cvspass task in Java. It's very interesting.

CVS passwords are stored in an encrypted format, but it's not a very secure algorithm. A lot of programmers know it, and there are all sorts of programs that can generate and crack the password.

The `<cvspass>` task is taking the password you give it, using that algorithm, and then adding it into the `.cvspass` file in your $HOME directory. In fact, if you're on Windows and are using CVSNT, this won't work and may even hang. (Maybe that's your issue?).

I have a program called [scramble.pl](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/433257/scramble.pl) that can take a password and then scramble it. Take that result and add it to the `.cvspass` file, and you'll be simulating what the `<cvspass>` task is doing. The format of `.cvspass` is fairly straight forward:

```
\1 <cvsRoot> <encryptedPasswd>
```

CVSNT writes these entries into the Windows Registry.

You can add `scramble.pl` to your project. Run that via an `<exec>` task, then use an `<echo>` task to append the entry onto the `.cvspass` file. If you're on Windows and using CVSNT, you can use `regedit` to add in the registry entry to do this.

Comment: Ya i can use exec command but how to pass the password? Is there any way it takes from a file bcoz i dont want manually entering of the password during execution

Comment: The password can be placed in the CVSROOT which you can pass directly to the cvs command via the `-d` parameter: `cvs -d :pserver:dweintraub:swordfish@servername:/cvs/root/dir checkout module_name`. The password is _swordfish_.

Comment: Hi thank you for response. But giving password in thr root is supported only for pserver . But i'm using ext. It gives following error 




cvs checkout: CVSROOT password specification is only valid for
cvs checkout: pserver connection method.
[checkout aborted]

Comment: @bhasker See my response appended to my answer.